# Node.js Google Cloud Platform Datastore date comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to run a query on Google Datastore using gcloud.js module:

```
var startDate = moment('2016-03-11').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var query = exports.dataset.createQuery('Resource')
  .filter('startDate', '>=', startDate);
exports.dataset.runQuery(query, function(err, resources) {
  console.log(resources);
});
```

This date comparison filter is not working, displaying all possible entities. Other filter types work perfectly fine.

I don't know in which format should I pass the date. Tried almost every possible format. Maybe the comparison operator for date should be different?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the variable type. It can't be a string, it shuold be parsed to Date:

```
.filter('startDate', '>=',  new Date(startDate));
```

Now everything works like a charm.

Comment: data in datestore is like string format. So how we can comare that?